# Setting environment variables (specifically the PYTHON PATH) on a mac

Tags: macos, variables, path, environment, pythonpath

Because it was such a mission to get this simple bit of info I've decided to post it for others:

1. In terminal execute:  mkdir ~/.MacOSX
2. In terminal execute:  touch ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
3. Browse to the file and open.
4. Paste:

   ```
       <key>DISPLAY</key>

       <string>:0.0</string>

       <key>PYTHONPATH</key>

       <string>/full/path/ofyour/favorite/script/dir:/full/path/of/another/script/dir:
   ```
5. Edit to what you need and save.

Comment: It's confusing to put the resolution inside the question text.  Instead, follow up with an answer.  That's why I edited it out in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documented way to do it with [Property List Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1067.html).

Note that you should use caution when setting environment variables this way as they apply to launched GUI applications which might not be expecting them.  For setting default environment variables when working in a terminal shell, the conventional UNIX way of using shell profile commands, like `.profile` or `.bash_profile` is preferred and less likely to break things.

Answer (score 1):

1. In terminal execute: `mkdir ~/.MacOSX`
2. In terminal execute: `touch ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`
3. Browse to the file and open.
4. Paste:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>DISPLAY</key>
    <string>:0.0</string>
    <key>PYTHONPATH</key>
    <string>/full/path/ofyour/favorite/script/dir:/full/path/of/another/script/dir:</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Edit to what you need and save.

<sub>(This was written by the original poster as part of the question.  Reposted as community wiki because I didn't write it, just cleaned up the formatting.)</sub>

Comment: Ah... how the hell did you do that? I tried but to no avail :(

Comment: @Jared: You need at least two blank lines between a numbered list and a code block.  Seems to be a quirk of the Stack Exchange formatting engine.